# Silverlight: binding to the result of a calculation that involes a property

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, data-binding

What I'd like to do is to not only bind a property X to a slider, but also bind the result of a calculation that involves X to a pie chart, so when user slide the slider, the pie chart updates automatically.

Below is what I have now. When I slide the "Food" slider, the pie chart updates accordingly. But nothing happens if the "rent" slider is moved. I'm guessing `renterInsurance.Value = rent.Value * 0.1` is evaluated only once, so any change in rent.Value later in the execution doesn't affect `renterInsurance.Value` at all. How do I achieve what I need? The real calculation might involve other properties/variables.

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{       
    public class Expense : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private string _Name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _Name; }
            set
            {
                _Name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

        private double _Value;
        public double Value
        {
            get { return _Value; }
            set
            {
                _Value = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Value");
            }
        }

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }             

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        PieSeries ps = exampleChart.Series[0] as PieSeries;

        List<Expense> expenses = new List<Expense>();  

        Expense food = new Expense();
        food.Name = "Food";
        food.Value = 50;
        sliderFood.DataContext = food;
        expenses.Add(food);

        Expense rent = new Expense();
        rent.Name = "Rent";
        rent.Value = 100;
        sliderRent.DataContext = rent;

        Expense renterInsurance = new Expense();
        renterInsurance.Name = "Renter's Insurance";
        renterInsurance.Value = rent.Value * 0.1;
        expenses.Add(renterInsurance);
        ps.ItemsSource = expenses;


    }       
}
```

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Height="700" Width="600">
    <Canvas Height="700" Width="600">                

    <toolkit:Chart Name="exampleChart" Height="300" Width="300" Canvas.Left="150" Canvas.Top="5">
        <toolkit:Chart.Series>
            <toolkit:PieSeries IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Name}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}" />                                    
        </toolkit:Chart.Series>
    </toolkit:Chart>

    <Slider Canvas.Left="11" Canvas.Top="65" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="158,254,0,0" Name="sliderFood" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" 
            Value="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <Slider Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="158,12,0,0" Name="sliderRent" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Canvas.Left="154" Canvas.Top="307" 
            Value="{Binding Value,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to modify the expense class so that it can subscribe to the propertyChanged event of other expense classes so you can wire up the renters insurance to the rent class and have it update its own value when it sees that rent.value changes.

I believe this line should work.  You can add it to the bottom of your constructor.

```
rent.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => {
  if (args.PropertyName == "Value")
    renterInsurance.Value = ((Expense)sender).Value * 0.1;
};
```

Comment: Thanks Malcolm. Could you point me to some example how the "subscribe" is done? I'm new to the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'll give it a shot when I can get back to work on this later this evening. Still trying to wrap my head around this - if I put this line in the definiton of the Expense class, wont' there be any error since neither "rent" nor "renterInsurance" exists at that point?

Comment: - okay, I guess you mean placing it in the MainPage().

Comment: yeah, sorry I mean't the constructor of the MainPage, not Expense.

Comment: Malcolm, I was able to give it a try and it worked great. Thanks again for your help!